# How to do Oracle Forms and JavaScript Integration for Java Web Start

Tags: java-web-start, oracleforms

Oracle Forms 12C has given little pointers for this at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/formsandreports/deploy-forms/oracle-forms-and-javascript-integration.htm#FSDEP-GUID-F38EE72E-FE26-49C0-AEC6-F5F9F65FBFFF

I have downloaded the Jetty jar and added to the jnlp files so that it could be downloaded to clients PC, however calling java script via WEB.JAVASCRIPT_EVAL_FUNCTION() gives me FRM-41848 JavaScript Execution is disabled during webstart session.

Any Help/Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/formsandreports/deploy-forms/GUID-97D44B82-347E-48D3-81C2-67B3C2F18A5F.htm#FSDEP757):

```
FRM-41848: JavaScript execution is disabled during webstart session.

Cause: JavaScript integration is not supported when running webstart.

Action: Use a browser if you want to run JavaScript integration with Oracle Forms.

Level: 15

Trigger: ON-ERROR
```

You'll have to run the application through a web browser.